# How to use serialize Collections.synchronizedList and co

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xstream

I am beginner to webservice. I was trying to write Restful webservice and i followed
http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54. This example works for me. But when i tried to implement the same on my code base it failed with below exception:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: XStream marshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Could not call java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject() : Could not call java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.writeObject() : Cannot reference implicit element  
---- Debugging information ----  
    implicit-element    : [EasyMock for class com.pyramid.qls.computeinvoker.Task]  

    referencing-element : /batchProgressMetrics/batchProgressUpdater/context/servletContext/context/attributes/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap/org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext/servletConfig/config/parent/lifecycle/listeners/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost_-MemoryLeakTrackingListener/outer-class/listeners/org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener/connector/service/connectors/org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector[2]/container/thread/group/threads/java.lang.Thread/threadLocals/table/java.lang.ThreadLocal_-ThreadLocalMap_-Entry[11]/value/org.easymock.classextension.internal.ClassProxyFactory_-1/val_-handler/delegate/control/state/behavior/behaviorLists/org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior/results/org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocationAndResults[4]/results/results/org.easymock.internal.Result/value/val_-value/java.util.Collections_-SynchronizedCollection/default/mutex  
-------------------------------  
message             : Could not call java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.writeObject()  
cause-exception     :   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$ReferencedImplicitElementException  
cause-message       : Cannot reference implicit element  
-------------------------------  
message             : Could not call java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject()  
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException  
cause-message       : Could not call java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.writeObject() : Cannot reference implicit element  
---- Debugging information ----   
    implicit-element    : [EasyMock for class com.pyramid.qls.computeinvoker.Task]  
    referencing-element : /batchProgressMetrics/batchProgressUpdater/context/servletContext/context/attributes/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap/org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext/servletConfig/config/parent/lifecycle/listeners/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost_-MemoryLeakTrackingListener/outer-class/listeners/org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener/connector/service/connectors/org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector[2]/container/thread/group/threads/java.lang.Thread/threadLocals/table/java.lang.ThreadLocal_-ThreadLocalMap_-Entry[11]/value/org.easymock.classextension.internal.ClassProxyFactory_-1/val_-handler/delegate/control/state/behavior/behaviorLists/org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior/results/org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocationAndResults[4]/results/results/org.easymock.internal.Result/value/val_-value/java.util.Collections_-SynchronizedCollection/default/mutex  
-------------------------------  
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)  
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)  
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)  
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I am using latest spring 3.0.5.RELEASE jars on windows. In addition to it i am using xstream-1.3.1 and xpp4-1.1.4. Can you please help me. Also if this is the limitation of Spring then can you please guide me through some of the examples where i can find restful webservice in action. I have seen examples using jaxb but there the issue was it doesn't support interface. Following is exception from my servlet xml
    
        
            
                
            
        
    
This is what i have in controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/clientMetrics/{clientId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public ModelAndView getBatchProgressMetrics(@PathVariable String clientId) {  
        List<BatchProgressMetrics> batchProgressMetricsList = null;  
        batchProgressMetricsList = batchProgressReporter.getBatchProgressMetricsForClient(clientId);  
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("QPRXmlView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "batchProgressMetrics", batchProgressMetricsList.get(0));  
        return mav;  
    }  
And on BatchProgressMetrics (is an interface) object i do have annotation:
    @XStreamAlias("batchProgressMetrics")  
    public class BatchProgressMetricsImpl implements BatchProgressMetrics
```

Comment: Spring 3.0.0.RC3 is very much *not* the latest version. Spring is currently at release 3.0.5. I doubt that's the problem, but there's no reason to be using a pre-release version of Spring.

Comment: Apologies. I am using 3.0.5.RELEASE on JDK1.6. Actually I though might be this excetion is in new version, so i tried reverting to old version and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an XStream problem rather than spring. A few things to look at:

- make sure `detectannotations` is set to true (as in the example)
- make sure the objects that you are sending as response are annotated with XStream annotations.

Also upgrade XStream (if not running the latest vesrsion)

If the problem is really that synchronized collections don't work (which I doubt), then before returning from your methods you can create a new collection from - `new ArrayList(syncedList)`. The result needs not be synchronized when sending over the wire.

Comment: Yeah i do have detectannotations as true: following is the xml excerpt <bean id="QPRXmlView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView"> <constructor-arg> <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller"> <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/> </bean> </constructor-arg> </bean> This is what i have in controller

Comment: problem with new ArrayList(synclist) is code owned by other team so i cant modify that.